# Fill the "na" values with unique "na" identifier when doing pandas merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to merge two pandas dataframe.

```
df1 = 
A   B
2   11
2   13
2   15
2   19
2   25
2   35
2   41
2   47
2   46
2   51
3   9
3   15
3   17
3   23
3   25
3   29
5   4
5   23
5   28
```

with another dataframe.

```
   df2 = 
A   B    C
2   11   abc
2   13   cdd
2   35   cdd
2   41   cdd
2   47   cdd
3   9   cdd
3   15   cdd
3   17   cdd
3   23   cdd
```

Both dataframes are sorted by "A" and then "B". I want to merge by `columns['A', 'B']`; so for column "C" where the data are missing I want to fill them by `na`, but with `na_uniqueNumber` for each missing block of `na`.

**How can I updated this merge method:**

```
data_frames = [df1, df2]
df_update = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(
    left, right, on=['A', 'B'], how='outer'), data_frames).fillna('na')
```

**Note:** The code should update `na` with unique values only in "C" in the situation other column are present.

**Expected output:**

```
   df2 = 
A   B    C
2   11   abc
2   13   cdd
2   15   na_01
2   19   na_01 
2   25   na_01  
2   35   cdd
2   41   cdd
2   47   cdd
2   46   na_02
2   51   na_02
3   9   cdd
3   15   cdd
3   17   cdd
3   23   cdd
3   25   na_03
3   29   na_03
5   4   na_04
5   23   na_04
5   28   na_04
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

IIUC

```
New = df_update[df_update.C == 'na']

s=New.reset_index().groupby('A').apply(lambda x : x['index'].diff().ne(1)).cumsum()

df_update.loc[df_update.C == 'na','C']+='_'+s.astype(str).str.pad(2,fillchar='0').values
df_update
Out[124]: 
    A   B      C
0   2  11    abc
1   2  13    cdd
2   2  15  na_01
3   2  19  na_01
4   2  25  na_01
5   2  35    cdd
6   2  41    cdd
7   2  47    cdd
8   2  46  na_02
9   2  51  na_02
10  3   9    cdd
11  3  15    cdd
12  3  17    cdd
13  3  23    cdd
14  3  25  na_03
15  3  29  na_03
16  5   4  na_04
17  5  23  na_04
18  5  28  na_04
```

Comment: For some reason this isn't working with my data. I have tried to see if there are any typos, but none yet. Doest this error message make sense `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'`.

Comment: this isn't working for some reason. `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'`. I think the issue is at this point `s.astype(str)` .

Comment: @everestial007 maybe change to s.apply(lambda x : x.astype(str))

Answer (score 3):

**Attempt 1**

```
def labels(d):
    mask = d.C.isnull().values
    a = d.A.values
    c = d.C.values.copy()
    i = np.flatnonzero(mask)
    f, u = pd.factorize([
        (a_, c_) for a_, c_ in zip(a[mask], (~mask).cumsum()[mask])
    ])
    c[i] = [f'na_{g+1:02d}' for g in f]
    return c


df1.merge(df2, 'left').assign(C=labels)

    A   B      C
0   2  11    abc
1   2  13    cdd
2   2  15  na_01
3   2  19  na_01
4   2  25  na_01
5   2  35    cdd
6   2  41    cdd
7   2  47    cdd
8   2  46  na_02
9   2  51  na_02
10  3   9    cdd
11  3  15    cdd
12  3  17    cdd
13  3  23    cdd
14  3  25  na_03
15  3  29  na_03
16  5   4  na_04
17  5  23  na_04
18  5  28  na_04
```

---

**Attempt 2**
also Python 3.6

```
def labeler():
    tracker = {}
    return lambda k: tracker.setdefault(k, len(tracker) + 1)

def fill(d):
    c_ = labeler()
    return [
        f'na_{c_((a, g)):02d}' if pd.isna(c) else c
        for a, c, g in zip(d.A, d.C, d.C.notna().cumsum())
    ]

df1.merge(df2, 'left').assign(C=fill)

    A   B      C
0   2  11    abc
1   2  13    cdd
2   2  15  na_01
3   2  19  na_01
4   2  25  na_01
5   2  35    cdd
6   2  41    cdd
7   2  47    cdd
8   2  46  na_02
9   2  51  na_02
10  3   9    cdd
11  3  15    cdd
12  3  17    cdd
13  3  23    cdd
14  3  25  na_03
15  3  29  na_03
16  5   4  na_04
17  5  23  na_04
18  5  28  na_04
```

---

**Attempt 3**
Another alternative.  Not sure what I like better.

```
def labeler(d):
    mask = d.C.notna()
    csum = mask.cumsum()
    tups = list(zip(d.A, csum, d.C, ~mask))
    trac = dict(map(reversed, enumerate(
        pd.unique([t[:2] for t in tups if t[-1]]), 1
    )))
    return list(map(
        lambda t: f'na_{trac.get(t[:2]):02d}' if t[:2] in trac else t[2], tups
    ))

df1.merge(df2, 'left').assign(C=labeler)

    A   B      C
0   2  11    abc
1   2  13  na_01
2   2  15  na_01
3   2  19  na_01
4   2  25  na_01
5   2  35    cdd
6   2  41    cdd
7   2  47  na_02
8   2  46  na_02
9   2  51  na_02
10  3   9    cdd
11  3  15    cdd
12  3  17    cdd
13  3  23  na_03
14  3  25  na_03
15  3  29  na_03
16  5   4  na_04
17  5  23  na_04
18  5  28  na_04
```

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared. Are these codes based on `python2.7` ?

Comment: No, 3.6 because of f-strings.  But you can use it with `str.format` instead.  I'm trying to get second option correct'er

Comment: yes that `f-strings` was saying `python 3.5 doesn't support 'f' prefix` .

Answer (score 2):

You can [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) first both `DataFrame`s by left join and then for each group `A` count `NaN`s, which are replaced by `fillna`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='left')

isna = df['C'].isnull()
count_nans =(isna.ne(isna.groupby(df['A']).shift()) & isna).cumsum().astype(str).str.zfill(2)
df['C'] = df['C'].fillna('na_' + count_nans)
print (df)
    A   B      C
0   2  11    abc
1   2  13    cdd
2   2  15  na_01
3   2  19  na_01
4   2  25  na_01
5   2  35    cdd
6   2  41    cdd
7   2  47    cdd
8   2  46  na_02
9   2  51  na_02
10  3   9    cdd
11  3  15    cdd
12  3  17    cdd
13  3  23    cdd
14  3  25  na_03
15  3  29  na_03
16  5   4  na_04
17  5  23  na_04
18  5  28  na_04
```