# pandas groupby is returning two groups for the same unique id

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a large pandas dataframe, where I am running groups by operations.

```
CHROM    POS    Data01    Data02 ......
1        ....................
1        ...................
2        ..................
2        ............
scaf_9   .............
scaf_9   ............
```

**So, i am doing:**

```
 my_data_grouped = my_data.groupby('CHROM')

 for chr_, data in my_data_grouped:
      do something in chr_
      write something from that chr_ data
```

Everything is fine in small data and in the data where there is no string type `CHROM` i.e `scaff_9`. But, with very large data and with `scaff_9`, I am getting two groups of `2`. It really isn't an error message and it is not affecting the computation. The issue is when I write the data by group in the file; I am getting two groups of `2` (splitted unequally).

It is becoming very hard for me to traceback the origin of this problem, since there is no error message and with small data it works well. **My only assumption are:**

- Is there certain limit on the the number of lines in total dataframe vs. grouped dataframe the `pandas` module can handle. What is the fix to this problem ?
- Among all the `2` most of them are treated as integer object and some (later part) as string object being close to `scaff_9`. Is this possible ?

Sorry, I am only making my assumption here, and it is becoming impossible for me to know the origin of the problem.

**Post Edit:**
I have also tried to run `sort_by(['CHROM'])` before doing to `groupby`, but the problem still persists.

Any possible fix to the issue.

Thanks,

Comment: Check the uniqueness of the column first using `df['CHROM'].unique()`. If you get the same things repeating twice then its the problem with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion there is data problem, obviously some whitespaces, so pandas processes each group separately.

Solution should be remove traling whitespaces first:

```
df.index = df.index.astype(str).str.strip()
```

You can also check unique strings values of `index`:

```
a = df.index[df.index.map(type) == str].unique().tolist()
```

---

If first column is not index:

```
df['CHROM'] = df['CHROM'].astype(str).str.strip()

a = df.loc[df['CHROM'].map(type) == str, 'CHROM'].unique().tolist()
```

EDIT:

Last final solution was simplier - casting to `str` like:

```
df['CHROM'] = df['CHROM'].astype(str)
```

Comment: I just tested my whole code. I just had to do `astype(str)` to fix the issue. I am assuming this is a bug (none fatal at least in my case). What is happening is that my `CHROM` start with string type `e.g scaff_9, ...`. I am doing a left merge before doing this groupby. So, pandas is litterally interpreting my `CHROM` as string, but when `CHROM 2` start it switches to intepreting it as `int`. I literally check my data by extracting the region where this grouping was being weird and there is `no whitespace`. Additionally, only doing `astype(str)` fixed the problem.

Comment: @everestial007 - Super, glad can help! :)

Comment: I am very much inclined to say that this is a bug (non fatal at least in my case). Just updated @Wes Mckinney on it via on other answer.

Comment: I have long been waiting for a comprehensive solution to this problem. Can you give it a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49284466/fill-the-na-values-with-unique-na-identifier-when-doing-pandas-merge

Comment: @everestial007 - I add solution for you, I understand it correct you want count `NaN`s per groups `A` ?